# updating uiimages dynamically

Tags: iphone, ios4, uiimageview, uiimage

Any examples available that update UIImageView images dynamically at a high rate? These images are received on a IP connection in a NSThread. But they don't update when I do imageView.image = newImageRecd;

EDIT: All data is recd on main thread

Appreciate any help/pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UI updates need to be performed on the main thread. If you are running the connection on a different thread, use:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateImageView:) withObject:newImageRecd waitUntilDone:FALSE];
```

where `updateImageView:` is the method used to set the image view's image property:

```
-(void)updateImageView:(UIImage *)image
{
    [self.imageView setImage:image];
}
```

Comment: Your question states "received on a IP connection in a NSThread". So, what do you mean by that?

Comment: The connection is established in an IBAction and a selector is called to receive data on the main thread.

Comment: In that case, you are performing everything on the main thread. To get the image view to update, perform the image download in the background using `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:`. Then you can update the image view using the code above when the download completes.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 4 and later, you can use Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) to load images on a background thread.  Here's a link that explains this process fully:

http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/

The tutorial above provides this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[cell imageView] setImage:image];
        [cell setNeedsLayout];
    });
});
```

I've been using this myself to load images from a remote server, and it's working great.